# How can I hide the clock from Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I would like to hide or remove the clock from my Windows 10 taskbar.

I did my research and the common way seems to go to "Custom Notification Icons"  -> "Hide and delete quick actions" and disable here the clock.

Problem is, I don't have the clock in this menu, even though it should be here if I trust the tutorial I saw.
Any tips ? What could I try ? My windows version is Windows 10 Professional.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Here's a screen of the windows. No clock in the list. I thought about a group policy but I seriously wonder why, especially where I don't see any other mark of group policy in our computer

[image]

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Windows 10 Pro, and I can disable the clock right there. Can you post a screenshot of what you see instead? That way we can identify if you are actually on the right page or not, or that something else is causing this.

Comment: I did it. Sorry it's in french, but I guess this not very important.

Comment: You are definitely on the wrong page. The page you are on is for the action center, not the taskbar.

Comment: too early in the morning. feel free to downvote. thanks for your help

Comment: Nah, I'm not going to downvote you simply because you didn't have your coffee yet. ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have just tried this on mine and this works, right click the date and time on the taskbar > taskbar settings > turn system icons on or off > the choose the clock option.

Comment: Win+I to open Settings then search for "Turn system icons on or off" then you can disable or enable the clock.

Comment: These are no longer available on Windows 11 version 22H2 build 22621.1194.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the Windows 10 desktop taskbar clock, we’ll need to make some changes in the Notifications & Actions section of the Windows 10 Settings app. To get there quickly, you can right-click on the clock in your taskbar and select Customize notification icons. This section of Settings allows the user to configure their desired Quick Actions, change which apps appear in the taskbar, and control notification settings. The option we’re looking for, however, is Turn system icons on or off. Click it to proceed to the next step.

Comment: Welcome to Super User refer this link, https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer just edit your post and I would like to suggest illustrate your command.

Comment: These are no longer available on Windows 11 version 22H2 build 22621.1194.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a screenshot of the settings. Since you have the french language in your windows OS
[image]

Just search for the title in the start menu and you shall find it.